# Importing CSV file by read.csv but the function recognize wrong number of columns

Tags: r, csv

I tried to import the CSV file from here: https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv using `read.csv` function:

```
WHO_data <- read.csv("https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv")
```

But the WHO_data I got has 12 columns and recognizes the first column as a row name.
I tried another method by getting a tibble instead of dataframe:

```
library(readr)
WHO_data <- read_csv("https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv")
```

It then gives the error below:

```
    Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row col   expected     actual                                                         file
  1  -- 12 columns 13 columns 'https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv'
```

Can anyone help me explain why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: `read_csv` doesn't generate an error but a warning. It reads the data correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file seem to be improperly formatted. There is an extra comma on the end of the second line. You can read the raw line data, remove the comma, then pass to read.csv. For example

```
file <- "https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv"
rows <- readLines(file)
rows[2] <- gsub(",$", "", rows[2])
WHO_data  <- read.csv(text=rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on the `data.table` package. If you want to return a `data.frame` (as opposed to `data.table`), you can additionally specify the argument `data.table=FALSE` to the `fread` function:

```
library(data.table)

file <- "https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv"

WHO_data <- fread(file, select=1:12, fill=TRUE)
```